# expectation of convex function of Poisson Binomial variable

Tags: summation, convex-analysis, expectation, binomial-distribution

I am working on the problem related to expectation of convex function of a Poisson Binomial variable. Any help would be appreciated.

First, there is a  Poisson Binomial distributed random variable $B$, i.e., $B = \sum_{i=1}^K x_i$, such that $x_i$ is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $P_i$. There is no necessity for variables $x_i$ to be identically distributed but they are independent.

Second, there is an objective function, $O = \sum_{k=0}^K P\{B=k\}\varphi(k)$. We can see that it is the expectation of $\varphi(B)$, where the function $\varphi$ is assumed to be a monotonically increasing and strictly convex function.

Then, we want to compare the objective functions with two different distribution of $x_i$. Assume that for each variable $x_i$, $P_{i,1}\le P_{i,2}$. Could we conclude that $O_1 \le O_2$ in general or under some special cases for the defined function $\varphi$?

What I have learned is that for variable $B$, $\operatorname{E}(B)=\sum_{i=1}^K P_i$ and the variance is $\operatorname{Var}(B) = \sum_{i=1}^K P_i(1-P_i)$. Intuitively, we know that the variance is increasing and strictly convex function of $B$. Since $\frac{\partial \operatorname{Var}(B)}{\partial P_i}=1-2P_i$, we coould conclude that it is monotonically increasing only when $P_i \le 1/2$. However, I need to demonstrate it without any other constraints on the distribution $P_i$.

Any other results under any specific convex function or more general solution would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You seem to assume that "binomial distribution" means the distribution of a random variable that is either $0$ or $1$.  Conventionally that is called a Bernoulli distribution, and although it is one instance of a binomial distribution, there are also other binomial distributions, namely the sum of a constant (i.e. non-random) number of i.i.d. Bernoulli-distributed random variables. You also mention "Poisson", so I thought you meant the Poisson distribution is somehow involved, and wondered if maybe you meant that $K$ is a Poisson-distributed random variable.  But not only$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$do you not say that, but later you treat $K$ as if it were not random a all, when you say a certain expected value and a certain variance depend on $K$. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you for your reply! First, it is my mistake to wirte the Bernoulli distribution as Binomial distribution. I will change it immudiately. Secondly, $K$ is a constant. According to Wikipidia, the sum of K independent Bernoulli distributed random variables is Poisson Binomial distributed, which has no direct relation with the well known Poisson distribution. And the binomial distribution is a special case for the Poisson Binomial with identical distribution across the Bernoulli random variables $x_i$. Thanks again and I will change the tag right now.